# Best practice with reducer and switch

Tags: typescript, switch-statement, reduce

I have this code in typescript:

```
type ACTIONTYPE =
  | { type: "SET_LIQUIDITY_DATA"; payload: ITVL[] | any }
  | { type: "SET_LIQUIDITY_BAR_DATA"; payload: ITVL[] | any}

function reducer(state: AppState, action: ACTIONTYPE) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SET_LIQUIDITY_DATA":
      return { tvl: action.payload, barChart: state.barChart };
    case "SET_LIQUIDITY_BAR_DATA":
      return { tvl: state.tvl, barChart: action.payload }
      default:
        return state  
  }
}
```

It works fine, the issue is that everytime i add an action i need to write a propertie field on each`return`field of the reduce function with the propertye, `state.nameOfThePropertie` if the action doesn't affect that field of the state and `action.payload`if it does.

I know that there's some way to work with it through descontruction but i lack the knowledge to do so.

Can someone give me a hint on how to work with it smarter?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who gets in here, that's how it's done:

```
function reducer(state: AppState, action: ACTIONTYPE) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SET_LIQUIDITY_DATA":
      return { ...state, tvl: action.payload };
    case "SET_LIQUIDITY_BAR_DATA":
      return { ...state, barChart: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```